# Is there equivalent of C++ "using" in Java (introducing alias for some class, or construction of classes)

Tags: java

I wonder if is there any equivalent of C++'s `using` in Java - I have pretty convoluted construction: `Map<String, ArrayList<Function<String, Map<String, String>>>> rules` and I would like to make it a little bit simpler by introducing something like:
`using Check = Function<Map<String, String>, TypeOfCheckResponse>`
and later defining `rules` (and other usages of `Check`) using it: `Map<String, ArrayList<Check>> rules`

Comment: No, there isn't; aside from avoiding types like `Map<String, ArrayList<Function<String, Map<String, String>>>>` in the first place.

Comment: You could use `var`.

Comment: @MCEmperor only if it's a local variable.

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer - thing is that I make this code only for "kata" in codewars, I just start to wonder if there is an equivalent keyword in Java, in the real-world application I would not use a construction like that, codewars solutions are limited to one file (I think)